# No permission for ls drwx--x--x

Tags: ls, chmod

Is there any way to see a tree of directories with a chmod of drwx--x--x ? I know I can manually check by bash script with if [ -d dirname ]. However it is not the solution I am looking for.

Cheers!

Comment: I think the answer depends heavily on whether you are the owner of the directories in question and whether you have root access to the system.

Answer (score 1):

No. You do not have read permissions on the directory and so you are unable to view the contents. Since you only have execute permissions, all you can do is attempt to use filesystem objects which may or may not exist within the directory.

Comment: I guess I am gonna use root and change the chmods. Guess no such protection against nephews. Thanks a lot.